# Clear the content of the UITextField's text property for tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextField called `place`, it's text property contains an `NSString`. I would like to clear the existing content from the text property when the user taps into the text field.

I tried the code above, but nothing happened. I also tried it with the placeholder property, but it was the same. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? I think it should work.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.place.text = nil;
}
```

2, version - in this case nothing appears in the text field from the beginning

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...

    [self textFieldDidBeginEditing:place];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.text = nil;
}
```

Comment: Is textFieldDidBeginEditing: being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property `clearsOnBeginEditing` you can set to `YES` programmatically or there is a checkbox in Interface Builder.

If you also want to clear your placeholder

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.placeholder = nil;
}
```

Double check that the `UITextField` self.place has it's delegate set to your view controller and validate that `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is being called.

Comment: It seems i missed it when i first tried to edit it in the interface builder, but now found it, thanks! This is the fastest solution.